# soapUI as Http tunnel to record iOS (iPhone/iPad) client-server discussions

Tags: ios, soapui, http-tunneling

I am trying to use soapUI as Http tunnel (https target) to record iOS client-server discussions, and then use it for service mocking to test my client which is an iOS app (iPhone and iPad) using the iPhone-Simulator. Unfortunately I don't manage to make it work.

Some more information:

I work on Mac.
I don't have WSDL but I think recording should work without it.
When I set my app to point to soapUI as http I see that soapUI gets my app's request. This of course don't go anywhere since my server is https.

Basically I think that my problem is setting soapUI to work with https. I need some help with how to configure the HTTP Tunnel - KeyStore and TrueStore values. Where can I find the values for these parameters? Is this somehow connected to ..../iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Library/Keychains/TrustStore.sqlite3 ?

BTW - this works perfectly with Charles Proxy, I can monitor the whole discussion without any issues. Charles Proxy uses its own certificate and I just had to approve it in my Keychain-Access app. I wanted to use soapUI in order to record whole discussions and replay them afterwards while soapUI serves as a mock server.

I would appreciate any help.
Thank you,
Ofer